# Issue updating curves in QwtPlot 6.1.3

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, qt4.8

I am currently working on Ubuntu 14.04, using gcc 4.9.2 and Qwt 6.1.3; I have installed **both** Qt 4.8.6 and Qt 5.2.1 (and I wonder whether this could be connected to the issues I am experiencing).

I have a simple GUI with a QwtPlot and a QwtPlotCurve attached, which I am trying to update and redraw. In the `setupUi()` function, I create a few random data points and then plot them:

```
void ExampleMainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow* mainWindow)
{
    // run the inherited setupUi
    Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(mainWindow);

    // associate internal pointer to main window
    this->mainWindow = mainWindow;

    // create some data points
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            this->createDataPoint();
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->xPlot.size(); i++)
    {
            cout << "Point #" << i << ": x=" << xPlot[i] << "; y=" << yPlot[i] << endl;
    }
    this->updateGraph();

    // also, connect stuff
    connect( this->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(synchronous()) );

    return;
}
```

Now, this part works as it should. The result is something like this:

[image]

Later, I connected the `pushButton` to a method that should add 10 points to the curve and replot it. The relevant methods are:

```
void ExampleMainWindow::synchronous()
{
    cout << "Creating 10 new data points..." << endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) this->createDataPoint();
    cout << "xPlot.size() = " << xPlot.size() << " ; yPlot.size() = " << yPlot.size() << endl;
    this->updateGraph();

    return;
}

void ExampleMainWindow::updateGraph()
{
    // detach everything?
    this->qwtPlot->detachItems();

    // create a new curve
    QwtPlotCurve* curve = new QwtPlotCurve("curve 1");
    curve->setSamples( QVector<double>::fromStdVector( xPlot ), QVector<double>::fromStdVector( yPlot ) );
    curve->attach( this->qwtPlot );
    this->qwtPlot->replot();
    //this->qwtPlot->show();

    return;
}
```

Now, the issue is that pressing the pushButton on the GUI does not visually change anything in the QwtPlot. I am sure the program enters `synchronous` when the pushButton is clicked. So, there is probably something wrong with the function `updateGraph`, but I am missing something, as I cannot find the issue.

When I compile the project, I use Qt 4.8.6, with

```
qmake-qt4
make
```

and I get no compiling errors. My Qt project file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app                                                         
TARGET = example
QT += widgets  
CONFIG += qwt
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
DEPENDPATH +=   ../. \                                                 
            # for Qwt                                              
            /usr/local/qwt-6.1.3-svn/lib \
            /usr/local/qwt-6.1.3-svn/include
            # end for Qwt
INCLUDEPATH +=  ../. \
            # for Qwt
            /usr/local/qwt-6.1.3-svn/include
            # end for Qwt
LIBS +=         -lqwt \              
            -L/usr/local/qwt-6.1.3-svn/lib                         

# Input                                                                
FORMS +=        example.ui                                             
HEADERS =       ExampleMainWindow.h                                    
SOURCES =       ExampleMainWindow.cpp \                                
            main.cpp
```

Even looking at the examples I found online, I am unable to find the problem. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance for your support :-)

**EDIT**: The phrase pointing out the issue was cut out by mistake.

Comment: So what is the issue? I think you forgot to mention what happens/does not happen when you press the button

Comment: Uops! :-/ One of the phrases was cut out. In brief, the method <code>updateGraph</code> does not update the QwtPlot widget. I am sure the program enters the method <code>synchronous</code> correctly, but nothing visually changes when <code>updateGraph</code> is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several trials and errors, I found a solution: I installed Qwt (I guess 6.0) through Ubuntu's Software Center, and removed all the other Qwt versions (6.1.2 and 6.1.3) that I had manually installed. Now, the small GUI is working properly.

I guess the error was due to some issue in the paths I provided in the .pro file, but I could not pinpoint the exact mistake. Not really a satisfying answer, but at least it works.